# Flutter: Firestore transaction crashes only on physical iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple transaction that updates a Firestore document. It works correctly on Android devices, Android Emulators and iOS emulators, but crashes on a **physical iOS device**:

```
Firestore.instance.runTransaction((Transaction tx) async {
    DocumentSnapshot docSnapshot = await tx.get(docRef);

      tx.update(
        docRef,
        {
          'title':'A Title'
        },
      );
    }
```

**Error:**

> -[NSError init] called; this results in an invalid NSError instance. It will raise an exception in a future release. Please call
>   errorWithDomain:code:userInfo: or initWithDomain:code:userInfo:. This
>   message shown only once.
>
> Assertion failure in void
>   firebase::firestore::core::Transaction::EnsureCommitNotCalled()(),
>   /Users/path_to_app/ios/Pods/FirebaseFirestore/Firestore/core/src/firebase/firestore/core/transaction.mm:198
>   *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL
>   ASSERTION FAILED: A transaction object cannot be used after its update
>   callback has been invoked. (expected !committed_)'

I'm not sure what the error means, and my Google quest has hit a dead-end. Really hoping someone can point out what the problem might be!

Comment: Sadly same here

Comment: It's an issue a number of people are experiencing including myself. https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1216

Comment: @Mr Jax did you found a solution for this?